# Where can I find my device product ID using ADB shell commands?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, 4.2-jelly-bean, shell, bootloader-lock

I want to unlock my device (Huawei G610-U20) bootloader but I'm unable to retrieve my product ID from common way

> *#*#1357946#*#*

Product ID is required by Huawei website to provide the unlocking code for bootloader.

I want to know where the product ID is stored in the android and is it possible to read it from adb shell? the device is already rooted.

I'm afraid that Product ID from lsusb is not what huawei is looking for.

Comment: Possibly mentioned on the buyer receipt? In my case, it was an online purchase and had that detail mentioned to support warranty. Please check that

Comment: @beeshyams I couldn't find it on the buyer receipt. It's an 8 digits code that stored somewhere on the device but I have no Idea where it could be.

Comment: Try [Device Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jphilli85.deviceinfo) app

Comment: Thank you but still no chance to get the product ID.

Answer (score 3):

I found this link after hours of searching and trying to unbrick my phone. Just type here https://imei24.com/ your IMEI number and it will show you all the info, hope it helps :)
BR!

Answer (score 0):

I think the product ID is displayed with this command, works only on stock ROM though.

```
 *#*#1357946#*#*
```

Alternatively, you can get the product ID with [Huawei Product ID Generator](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3020890&d=1416283551)

UPDATE : 
Try this [generator](http://rootjunkysdl.com/files/Huawei%20P8%20Lite/Huawei%20unlock%20bootloader.zip)

Comment: The code you mentioned doesn't work on my device and about Huawei Product ID Generator, I should say my device is not listed and even I tried another devices to use on Huawei website but look like there is no go.

Comment: On your question you said : ##1357946##

Comment: Look like a typo.

Comment: So? did it work or not.

Comment: Nope. the reason that I'm looking to find an alternative way is that my device doesn't respond to this code.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing phone language to english uk and dial up that number again.That worked.for.me